# Complex jquery scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I need to trigger a function specifically after an user scroll almost at the bottom of the page then up until certain point. How do I do it properly?

[image: Image as helper]

```js
advertisement.refreshAd = function() {
   $(window).scroll(function(event) { 
     if('almost at the end then scroll up to certain point') 
     {console.log('trigger refresh!');}
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
advertisements.refreshAd = function() {
    var furthestPoint = false;
    var point2 = 1700 //will be dynamic;

    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var scrolledToPosition = false;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();

        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
            furthestPoint = true;
        }
        if (st < lastScrollTop && st < point2 && furthestPoint){
            if (!scrolledToPosition) {
                console.log('TRIGGER! - once only!');
                scrolledToPosition = true;
            }
        }

        lastScrollTop = st;
    });
};
advertisements.refreshAd();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the jQuery function `scrollTop()`. The code would look something like this:

```js
var atEnd = false;
advertisement.refreshAd = function() {
   $(window).scroll(function(event) { 
      if($(document).scrollTop() > $(document).height()-500) { //point1
          atEnd = true;
      } if (($(document).scrollTop() < point2) && atEnd){                 
          console.log('trigger refresh!');
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
    <script>
        var touchedBottom = 0;
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(event) { 
          if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() == jQuery(document).height()) {
            touchedBottom = 1;
            console.log("touched Bottom");
          }
          if(touchedBottom){
              if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() < jQuery("#point_2").offset().top){
                    touchedBottom = 0;
                    console.log("touched point 1");
              }
          }
       });
    </script>
```